# Block js when using <meta http-equiv="refresh"

Tags: javascript, refresh, meta, referer

I'm redirecting visitors in some situations to hide referer by using:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=//NewURL">`

But my analytics js script run before redirect so it detects referer. Is it possible to block js in redirect situation? Or can I use some other redirect method to loose referer info?

Answer (score -1):

It was very simple. If somebody needs it: You can just close head, body,html tags and exit script in php.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
<?php
  $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  if (strpos($ref,'UNWANTED_REFERER')!== false)
    {$newurl="//".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=".$newurl."\">";
    echo "</head><body></body></html>";
    exit(0);
    }
?>
```